# HttpClientModule http post with headers not working

Tags: typescript, angular6

I can't able to get the response from the server using angular httpclientmodule,
I'm completely new to angular6 httpclientmodule, please find the below code

myservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {

  response: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


 getLogin(mobileNumber, loginPassword) {
  let headers= new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json').set('X-Authorization','clientmobileClient1').set('username',mobileNumber).set('password',loginPassword);
    return this.http.post('http://My API URL', null, {headers}).map((response: any) => response.json());

  }
}
```

mycomponent.ts

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.service.getLogin(mobileNumber, loginPassword).subscribe((response: any) => { console.log("my response", response) });
}
```

Please help me out where I'm wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
let Params = new HttpParams();
    Params = Params.append('username', mobileNumber);
    Params = Params.append('password', loginPassword);
const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','X- 
    Authorization':'clientmobileClient1' });
    var options = { headers: header, params: Params };
    return this.http.post('http://My API URL', {}, options);
```

Comment: I tried, but im not passing the arguments as a parameters each as a seperate headers @lesiano

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` to add my headers to my HTTP request but. Here is how i set my headers for a request. I have noticed you are sending the `username` & `password` in the heads this is not best practice.

This is how i would do yours

```ts
getLogin(mobileNumber, loginPassword) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type','application/json')
    .set('X-Authorization','clientmobileClient1')
    .set('username',mobileNumber)
    .set('password',loginPassword);
  return this.http.post<any>(
    'http:://url.api',
    {}, // Because its a post request
    { headers: headers }
  ).pipe(map(response => {
    return response;
  }))
}
```

But i would rather do that as a get request like this

```ts
getLogin(mobileNumber, loginPassword) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type','application/json')
    .set('X-Authorization','clientmobileClient1')
    .set('username',mobileNumber)
    .set('password',loginPassword);
  return this.http.get<any>(
    'http:://url.api',
    { headers: headers }
  ).pipe(map(response => {
    return response;
  }))
}
```

But i would rather do it like this, With sending the sensitive data in the body of request. like below. But this will all depend on how you have write your API.

```ts
getLogin(mobileNumber, loginPassword) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type','application/json')
    .set('X-Authorization','clientmobileClient1');
  return this.http.post<any>(
    'http:://url.api',
    {
      mobileNumber,
      loginPassword
    },
    { headers: headers }
  ).pipe(map(response => {
    return response;
  }))
}
```

If needs i can include the code of setting up `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`

Comment: i have also used the interceptors but still the issue exists, any other solutions to this @SCRATK